# ACL Permissions and new CMS

Tags: wordpress, drupal, permissions, acl

Recently we had a civicrm install under Drupal. We have changed the install to wordpress for several reasons. Under the Drupal version we had certain users who had a branch role. They could log in and only see those members who were in that branch(group). They could not see all members in all 15 branches.

After changing to Wordpress we used a backup of a civicrm db. Whilst all ACL's are still as they were, when a branch committee member logs into the new Civicrm, they can now see all members in all branches rather than the single branch that they used to only see.

ANy ideas as to the difference between Drupal and Wordpress and is it something that we can fix easy or might require custom coding?

Cheers

Comment: Have you gone through the WordPress permissions page and set then appropriately? How are you syncing the WordPress users (and their roles/capabilities) with their respective CiviCRM contacts?